# Maven - Is an input file for source generating a source or a resource?

Tags: java, maven, resources

I have a project which generates classes. This project requires an input JSON which defines the schema, models, ... for these classes.

In the Maven world, should this input file be considered as a **source** or **resource**?

Comment: I'd call it a resource.  Most importantly, I'd make clear that it's generated.  (I do when I use JAXB.)

Comment: Does it need to compile? If yes then source or else resource. Primarily opinion based question though.

Comment: I would say **neither**. If this file is just to generate some classes it has no business being in the final build artefact - unless it has some other purpose. Therefore I would put it in some other folder outside of `src`.

Comment: @duffymo I think the question is about the input JSON, not the generated code.

Comment: @lexicore Correct!

Comment: I knew that.  Just using JAXB as an example of something generated that you'll want to clean up easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to sonsider with complete paths. For resource it would be `src/main/resources`. For source you'll need somethin `src/main/<here>`. Should it be `src/main/json`? Does not look right for me so I'd opt to `src/main/resources`.

**Update** XML Schemas in modules which use JAXB schema compiler (XJC) are often put in `src/main/resources`, sometimes in `src/main/schema`.

Comment: If the name of the generator project is 'mighty-generator', it might be a good idea to put the input files in `src/main/mighty-generator`? Then, is this directory `mighty-generator` a source or a resource directory?

Comment: I strongly disagree. Leaking this information into the final build artefact is a Bad Idea. This file has no business being anywhere is `src`.

Comment: @BasOpers it is neither, it is project meta-data. Similar to the `pom.xml`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I agree that the file should not be in the final build. However, you can define which files should be included and which should be excluded in Maven. You could exclude `src/main/mighty-generator/**`? Or even not declare `src/main/mighty-generator` as a resource directory to start with?

Comment: @BasOpers I am fully aware of that. But there is no reason to battle Maven in this case, these files do not end up in the artefact and therefore do not belong in `src`. There are situations where it is necessary to place files into the output directory structure and then exclude them; this is not one of them.

Comment: I might be wrong, but if you don't mention `src/main/mighty-generator` in the pom.xml, Maven completely ignores it. Though, I understand your view to have it outside `src` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

As a reference example: ANTLR, a well known parser generator, expects the grammar in `src/main/antlr4`. See http://www.antlr.org/api/maven-plugin/latest/examples/simple.html.

Likewise, if the name of the generator project is `mighty-generator`, it might be a good idea to put the input files in `src/main/mighty-generator`.